# filtering for max value in collection in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection of models having structure:

{"name":"xyz","company":"abc","recNumber":"M34/14-15/23"}

I need to get that specific model from this collection whose recNumber is highest(based on number after last slash). I guess it can be done with .filter from underscore but don't know what will be the exact construct in this case.

Answer (score 6):

try this;

```
model = collection.max(function(m){
  return _.last(m.get('recNumber').split('/'));
});
```

`collection.max()` Returns the maximum value in list.

`_.last(array)` Returns the last element of an array.

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x4ZT3/)