# BackboneJS - get specific value from Model using .max

Tags: backbone.js

So I have this:

```
var competitionModel = new Competition.CompetitionModel();
competitionModel.contest_id = this.contest_id;
this.insertView('.comp', new Competition.View({model: competitionModel}));
competitionModel.fetch();
```

So far so good, the Model and its (selected) values are getting display in the `<div class="comp">`.

Now I want to get a specific value from the same Model, in this case `profile_image` and it has to be the MAX value from the model. I read something about `.max()`-method but I dont know how to use it

I have this structure:

```
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="comp"></div>
```

1) is it possible? 2) can I use the same methods? like `this.insertView('.image', blablab)`

So, could anyone help me out?

Comment: Max of what? is it a collection or a model which has a property that is a list of things?

Comment: I want the max value of a property inside the Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, judging by your comment the property is an array of things.

You cannot use the backbone `max` (which only applies to collections) but you can use the underscore `max` (they are the same thing, in the end, the former is a wrapper for the latter but let's not go into the details). You can see the collection `.max()` in action [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247111/filtering-for-max-value-in-collection-in-backbone-js).

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var max = _.max(competitionModel.get("property"));
```

Eventually you can pass a function to transform values:

```
var max = _.max(competitionModel.get("property"), function (element) {
     // element is a single item in the list, return a number here.
});
```

Alternatively you can also use the underscore wrapper like this:

```
var max = _(competitionModel.get("property")).max(function (e) { ... });
```

More on `max()` can be found in the [Underscore Docs](http://underscorejs.org/#max).